# Why is CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors() returning nil in this case?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

When I use the following code:

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginf1.png"];
CGImageRef rawImageRef=image.CGImage;

const float colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};

CGImageRef maskedImageRef=CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(rawImageRef, colorMasking);
```

`maskedImageRef`is always nil.  Why is this, and what can I do to correct this?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. The `CGImageRef` you are creating has only 6 bytes for each pixel with byte with no alpha channel. The masking function needs a `CGImageRef` with 8 bytes for each pixel, only 6 of them used, with no alpha channel. At least, I *think* this is what's causing it.

Anyway, fix it by creating a bitmap context, drawing your image to that bitmap context, then getting your CGImageRef from `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.

Comment: I can add a data point to this interpretation. CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors seems to dislike creating masked images from images with an active alpha channel. Which does kinda make sense: When in Rome - or at least, when using images (such as PNG) with alpha channels, use the built in alpha channel for masking .

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is failing is because you CANNOT create a mask image with an alpha channel.  Unfortunately what you are trying to is NOT possible.

The only way to use "CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(...)" it to provide it a bitmap context WITHOUT an alpha channel.  The catch 22 here is that it is NOT possible to create a bitmap context WITHOUT an alpha channel.  Don't you just love Apple?

Comment: How do you know that his image is an alpha channel?

Comment: Here's a bitmap context without an alpha channel: `CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, W, H, 8, W, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.None.toRaw()))`

Comment: Or you can use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, true, 0)` (i.e. a `true` value for `opaque` option).