# iOS color to transparent in UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

How can I clear out the magenta part of an UIImage and make it transparent?

I've looked through numerous answers and links on SO and nothing works (e.g. [How to make one color transparent on a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage/1108300#1108300) answer 1 removes everything but red, answer 2 apparently doesn't work because of [Why is CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors() returning nil in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563770/why-is-cgimagecreatewithmaskingcolors-returning-nil-in-this-case)).

**Update:**

If I use CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors with the UIImage I get a nil value. If I remove the alpha channel (I represent the image as JPEG and read it back) CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors returns an image painted with a black background.

**Update2, the code:**

Returning nil:

```
const float colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(anchorWithMask.CGImage, colorMasking);

NSLog(@"image ref %@", imageRef);
// this is going to return a nil imgref.

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

Returning an image with black background (which is normal since there is not alpha channel):

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(anchorWithMask, 1.0)];

const float colorMasking[6] = {222, 255, 222, 255, 222, 255};
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(inputImage.CGImage, colorMasking);

NSLog(@"image ref %@", imageRef);
// imgref is NOT nil.

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
```

**Update3:**

I got it working by adding the alpha channel after the masking process.

Comment: @MB How did you "add the alpha channel after the masking process?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

const float colorMasking[6] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image.CGImage, colorMasking)];
```

You receive nil, because parameters, that you send is invalid. If you open Apple documentation, you will see this:

> *Components*
>   An array of color components that specify a color or range of colors
>   to mask the image with. The array must contain 2N
>   values { min[1], max[1], ... min[N], max[N] } where N is the number of
>   components in color space of image. Each value in components must be a
>   valid image sample value. If image has integer pixel components, then
>   each value must be in the range [0 .. 2**bitsPerComponent - 1] (where
>   bitsPerComponent is the number of bits/component of image). If image
>   has floating-point pixel components, then each value may be any
>   floating-point number which is a valid color component.

You can quickly open documentation by holding Option + Mouse Click on some function or class, like CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors.

Comment: I just tried this and it's returning a completely transparent uiimage.

Comment: This is how the input image looks like: http://i.imgur.com/lxJdm.png (this is the png version, internally it's an UIImage from UIImagePicker)

Answer (score 4):

I made this static function that removes the white background you can use it replacing the mask with the color range you want to remove:

```
+ (UIImage*) processImage :(UIImage*) image
{
    const float colorMasking[6]={222,255,222,255,222,255};
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(image.CGImage, colorMasking);
    UIImage* imageB = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return imageB;
}
```

Comment: It is working on my project and I am removing the white color range. I think you specify colors range like in this one I use from 222 -> 255 for Red to be removed. I may not be understanding it 100% but you could try it again with the range you need.

Comment: @khaledannajar I have used this code it's work perfect but still some white pixcel can't remove from border of blank line which I have drawn  programatically in my app

Comment: @keyur bhalodiya You can try changing the ranges of the white color (making it wider) other than that I don't know how to help you. :(

Answer (score 0):

I did this in CIImage with the post-processing from Vision being a pixelBuffer:

```
    let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    let filteredImage = ciImage.applyingFilter("CIMaskToAlpha")
    self.picture.image = UIImage(ciImage: filteredImage)
```