# Set transparency in image IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a table view, I have addeed image as subview for header, but that image is shown with bagckground white color,how to set transparency for image.

TIA

Comment: Does your image infact *have* a transparent background?

Comment: If you don't mind, how to set transparent background for image.

Comment: this would have to be done via an image editor.

Comment: `[_ImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For this you have to set alpha of your UIImageView

```
Your_ImageView.alpha = 0.6;
```

You can also do it in your xib file

Comment: I am adding image programatically. By the way setting alpha low hides the visibility of image also.. Any Idea?

Comment: if you are adding it programatically then you can use the line Your_ImageView.alpha = 0.6; and make sure the image you are using must have transparent backgroung

Comment: @naveen this will set the transparency for the *full* image, the OP is looking to make the background transparent.

Comment: @James For this you have to make an image with transparent background and your question should be image with transparent background not the transparent image

Comment: @James, May be my question is wrong I want transparent background only, sorry for that. I have transparent background image only still I need to do anything in code. ?

Comment: @james try giving your imageview background color as clearcolor this may help you

Comment: @naveen `For this you have to make an image with transparent background` - not true, you can use image masking see my answer.

Comment: @James thanks for that..as a beginner i have many things to learn :) and sorry for misunderstanding :(

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the name of your view is myTransparentSubView:

```
[myTransparentSubView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

If you are using the Interface Builder then set the background Color property accordingly within IB.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to infact to create an image with a transparent background, however, you can use an [Image Mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html) to get the desired effect.

There is already an example of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311049/ios-color-to-transparent-in-uiimage).

Answer (score -1):

Use image Preview in MAC

Start with a png file.

You have to go to View > Show Edit Toolbar.

Then widen the window so that you can see all of the icons.

Then click the icon that looks like a magic wand.

And then click and drag on the color you want to erase.