# iPhone: Remove the white background of some image came from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make one color transparent on a UIImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633722/how-to-make-one-color-transparent-on-a-uiimage)

I've some images came from Server as URL and then I download and draw them on Cells of  UITableView.

The images have white background. **I need to remove this background to make the image transparent**.

I'll rephrase it: Is there a way to detect and recognize white spaces surrounding the component inside the photo, So I delete them and recreate the image? you know like face recognition.

Note: the background is part of the image itself.

Comment: Have a look at the link left by @MattB, but if the image is a JPEG, I do not think it will be that easy.

Comment: I think the answer is in this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8311049/ios-color-to-transparent-in-uiimage